# passing variables from JavaScript to php (through fetch api)

Tags: javascript, php, fetch-api

I am trying to post my variable javascript to php file.
I don't able to post variables, but able to pass json data.

my code like this.

```
     var check = 'hello';
     var check1 = 'hello1';

    fetch('http://localhost/react_task/react-webpack-boilerplate/php/api.php', {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            a: 2, // here passing variable doesn't work 
            b: 1  // like check and check1 does't show any values while passing here
        })
    }) .then(function(response) {
            if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
                return response.text()
            }
            throw new Error(response.statusText)
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
    })
```

can you please guide me, how to pass variables from JavaScript to php.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ya you can do it using ajax :
Just an example ;;;

```
var a=10;
var b=20;
$.post('abc.php',{param1:a,param2:b},function(data){
 //here action on data returned or anything
});
```

Comment: i am working with react-js and working on file type jsx.. so its hard to use ajax in jsx file format